# Problem with GNU GRUB popping during start of OS system

Tags: command-line, grub2, bash, gnu

I tried to delete Ubuntu and deleted a disk partition from Windows 10. Now I'm stuck at the GNU Command Line and I don't know how to exit this because I'm not familiar with Linux and Ubuntu. How can I get back to Windows 10. And can I actually delete GRUB from command line?

Thanks

Comment: Grub is found in the /boot/grub/ directory of the Ubuntu partition. If you've deleted that partition already (from within windows 10 as you described), grub is already deleted.  Grub rescue appears because it cannot run and you've a hanging pointer that is trying to run but cannot find itself as it was deleted. It can no longer be fixed by Ubuntu (it was deleted), and the MBR must be fixed by an OS on your system (ie. the `bootrec` command from windows 10 will correct it). It should be performed before you delete the Ubuntu partition, but windows 10 media will correct it.

Comment: Can I go to F10 and then change Boot to Windows 10 without DVD/CD or USB?

Comment: Or how do I get to Windows

Comment: The keys and processes used to start windows 10 are dictated by your hardware (it maybe F9, blue, black, F12, or other buttons depending on brand & model of device). Some machines come with recovery media, others you just hit a key to operate (being stored on the device itself). but neither hardware or Windows relate to Ubuntu,  `bootrec` (boot record) is a windows 10 command is executed from within windows 10.